# Outdated contract-api documentation

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract

Trying to follow these examples:

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/code#create-a-blueprint

which fails with:

```
createBlueprint is not a function
```

Seems like the examples in the documentation are diverged from the implementation? Is there a more up-to-date example, or better yet API documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current `api-contract` documentation is very outdated. We are working on updating it as we speak.

The `createBlueprint` is no longer available. You can use `CodePromise` to upload and instantiate new code and `BlueprintPromise` to instantiate code that is already on-chain.

The 2 classes respectively map to the `instantiate_with_code` and `instantiate` dispatchables in the Substrate FRAME contracts pallet

In both cases you would instantiate by calling `tx[constructorName]` on the resulting object (code or blueprint) with the right arguments.

You can read more about the arguments in the [metadata section](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#instantiatevalue-compactu128-gas_limit-compactu64-storage_deposit_limit-optioncompactu128-code_hash-h256-data-bytes-salt-bytes)
and also refer to the implementation in Polkadot.js Apps for [Blueprint](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/e9bb234b1fa9f4d7f227808fc0c9ff6a00db0b40/packages/page-contracts/src/Contracts/Deploy.tsx#L57) and [Code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/e9bb234b1fa9f4d7f227808fc0c9ff6a00db0b40/packages/page-contracts/src/Codes/Upload.tsx#L44).